# Matplotlib plots on VS Code jupyter notebook takes all the width

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Plot on VS Code jupyter notebook takes all the width on cell output. Before June update this wasn't a problem. Problem is on dark theme it creates too much unnecessary white space. Does anyone know the reason?

[image: image of vs code plot]

Comment: Try this at the top of your code after ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt```: ```plt.rcdefaults()```. This would restore it back to original size.

Answer (score 1):

you can "fix" it for your current notebook session by resetting matplotlib option back to default .

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

If you check on the [vs code notebook docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks), you can see the same white space appears in their screenshots.